# How to get the list of child nodes from firebase database reference?

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

[image: DB Structure]

Below I've attached the picture of DB Structure and I'm trying to get the list of child nodes from firebase DB reference (timingInformation). How can I get the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To read/synchronize data from the Firebase Database, you'll need to attach a listener. A simple case:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("timingInformation");
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildRemoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onChildMoved:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
};
```

For more see the [Firebase documentation on loading data from a list](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events), and the [reference documentation on what you can do with a snapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot).